# Filter values from an array of hashes and delete them from the original array

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, hash

I am struggling to find the proper way to filter an array of hashes, removing the entries that matched with the filter condition, while returning these deleted hashes. Here's an example of this `magic_function!` which does what I am trying to achieve:

```rb
my_array = [{ id: 1, val: 'foo' }, { id: 2, val: 'bar' }, { id: 3, val: 'baz' }]

extracted_hashes = my_array.magic_function! { |hash| hash[:id] == 1 }
# [{ id: 1, val: 'foo' }]

my_array
# [{ id: 2, val: 'bar' }, { id: 3, val: 'baz' }]
```

---

The reason I am trying to do this is because the array is a huge collection of database rows and I need to process them, using values from another array of IDs to process. (that part cannot change unfortunately, restricting rows from the database would be much more efficient)

Using `Array.filter` allows me to grab the correct hashes but iterating every time over the full length of the array. Since I won't be needing the hashes that have already been processed, I assume deleting them from the original array will make it smaller and smaller, reducing the amount of iterations needed to filter the next IDs until all IDs have been processed and there is nothing left in the original array.

Comment: You don't need to remove them from the array. If you can make a new array which is a subset (using `filter`) that's fine. And yeah check out [Enumerable#partition](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/partition)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to separate the input array into 2 arrays based on the filtering condition. You can modify the input array in place too, by using it on the left-hand side of the assignment:

```
my_array = [{ id: 1, val: 'foo' } , { id: 2, val: 'bar' } , { id: 3, val: 'baz' }]

# split input array into 2 new arrays, keep input array as is:
selected, other = my_array.partition { |hash| hash[:id] == 1 }

puts "#{selected}"   # [{:id=>1, :val=>"foo"}]
puts "#{other}"      # [{:id=>2, :val=>"bar"}, {:id=>3, :val=>"baz"}]


# remove from the input array selected elements into 1 new array,
# keep the rest in the input array (change the input array in-place):
selected, my_array = my_array.partition { |hash| hash[:id] == 1 }

puts "#{selected}"  # [{:id=>1, :val=>"foo"}]
puts "#{my_array}"  # [{:id=>2, :val=>"bar"}, {:id=>3, :val=>"baz"}]
```

---

Note that `partition` can be thought of as both `select` and `reject` (or `filter` and `reject`) in a single operation. Here is a simple example to illustrate what `partition` does:

```
x, y = [3, 2, 1, 4].partition { |n| n < 3 }
puts "#{x}; #{y}"   # [2, 1]; [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

`my_array.magic_function!` indicates you wish to create a method on the class `Array`. I would advise against that, letting `my_array` be an argument instead. You could write your method as follows.

```
def magic_function!(arr)
  (arr.size-1).downto(0).with_object([]) do |i,a|
    a.unshift(arr.delete_at(i)) if yield(arr[i])
  end
end
```

```
my_array = [{ id: 1, val: 'foo' }, { id: 2, val: 'bar' }, { id: 3, val: 'baz' }]
```

```
magic_function!(my_array) { |h| h[:id] == 2 }
  #=> [{:id=>2, :val=>"bar"}] 
my_array
  #=> [{:id=>1, :val=>"foo"}, {:id=>3, :val=>"baz"}]
```

Here is a second example (after setting `my_array` equal to its original value).

```
magic_function!(my_array) { |h| h[:id] == 1 || h[:id] == 3 }
  #=> [{:id=>1, :val=>"foo"}, {:id=>3, :val=>"baz"}] 
my_array
  #=> [{:id=>2, :val=>"bar"}]
```

See [Array#delete_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at). Notice that it is necessary to remove elements from `my_array` in reverse order because the argument is changing while the method is executed.

Comment: I would have used `Enumerable#partition` had it not already been taken...

Comment: `partition` seems the most adapted, but that `yield` solution also seems very elegant to me. Learning a lot from this, thank you!